Can't install YAML with cpan
I am very new to Perl. I am trying to install some modules with cpan.
Everytime I use install YAML
I get the following
Failed during this command:
 RJBS/Test-Deep-1.204.tar.gz                  : make NO
 INGY/Spiffy-0.46.tar.gz                      : make NO
 RJBS/Algorithm-Diff-1.201.tar.gz             : make NO
 INGY/Test-Base-0.89.tar.gz                   : make NO
 INGY/YAML-1.31.tar.gz                        : make NO
 NEILB/Text-Diff-1.45.tar.gz                  : make NO
 TINITA/Test-YAML-1.07.tar.gz                 : make NO

Here is another example. When I use cpan YAML::Tiny I get
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading 'C:\Users\omars\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 10 Aug 2024 14:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'YAML::Tiny'
Checksum for C:\Users\omars\.cpan\sources\authors\id\E\ET\ETHER\YAML-Tiny-1.74.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/YAML-Tiny-1.74.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for YAML::Tiny
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  ETHER/YAML-Tiny-1.74.tar.gz
  C:\Users\omars\AppData\Local\ActiveState\cache\5a8e6838\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/YAML-Tiny-1.74.tar.gz
'gmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  ETHER/YAML-Tiny-1.74.tar.gz
  gmake -- NOT OK


I use Windows. Perl version (I installed it from vstudio)

It says 'gmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command so I'd try to install Gnu Make first. Many Perl modules are make-based.

Ok I can now run make commands in CMD but not gmake which cpan uses. Do you know how to solve this issue? @robert

No, sorry, I don't use Windows or Visual Studio. Maybe you can create a gmake.bat that just calls make.

Which Perl are you using? Strawberry Perl is in my experience better for Windows

I use Activestate not Strawberry

@TLP Installing Strawberry Perl instead of activestate did solve the issue. Thanks a lot !

@OmarMohsen I had the same problem with ActiveState. I changed to Strawberry, and no more problems. If you want, you can write an answer to your own question to get it resolved.

ActivePerl expects you to use its state tool on install modules since part of their value proposition is that the repository they manage is known and safe.
Strawberry Perl acts like the standard Perl setup where you can use cpan (or cpanm), and come with the various third-party things, such as gmake, to let that work.
